# How to set order for SessionRepositoryFilter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-session

I am evaluating spring-session with my web application. During the very first request to the web app, multiple httpsession is being created for a single client. After debugging I found that the problem is, the response is committed earlier in the filter chain by ShallowEtagHeaderFilter before reaching SessionRepositoryFilter, so the cookie added to the response is not sent to the client. so, every further ajax request creates a new session, but the session id is not set in the cookie.

I'm trying to move SessionRepositoryFilter after ShallowEtagHeaderFilter. is there a way to do it?

filter config:

```java
@Bean
public SessionRepositoryFilter sessionFilter(RedisOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository) {
    HttpSessionStrategy cookieStrategy = new CookieHttpSessionStrategy();
    ((CookieHttpSessionStrategy) cookieStrategy).setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
    SessionRepositoryFilter sessionRepositoryFilter = new SessionRepositoryFilter(sessionRepository);
    sessionRepositoryFilter.setHttpSessionStrategy(cookieStrategy);
    return sessionRepositoryFilter;
}
```

filter is registered by:

```java
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addFilter("sessionFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class)
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, "/*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment, you can register a filter *for any `url-pattern`* using `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or in a *spring* way you can do it in the application configuration class, like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext
            .addFilter("sessionFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class)
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```